# How to have pc at boot up give me a choice of either operating system to load

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot

I am running windows 7 on a 1tb hard drive on my desktop pc.I just installed a second 2tb hard drive into the same desk top pc.I wanted to install windows 10 to that new second 2tb hard drive.I did install a new copy of windows 10 onto that 2nd hard drive.everything loaded properly. I had read on here that when I would boot up I would be able to choose what operating system I want to boot into.every time I reboot my pc it now only boots to the new windows 10 operating system I just installed.never does it give me a choice. What can I do now to be able to choose which operating system I want it to boot up.

Comment: I may be wrong, but you need to look at the boot sequence in the BIOS. Press Delete from starting up from a cold boot to access bios.
You can also hold a key down on boot to be prompted for the bootable device, ESC, F1, F2, F8 or F10   It can be either of these it depends on your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the boot order in the Bios:
https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+change+boot+order

Or alternatively, you can add your old installation, in the boot manager like this:
https://youtu.be/LPxP-9rrHaA?t=133

Comment: I figured I could change the boot order,but will I have to do that every time I want to switch between 7 an 10?

Comment: Yes, unless you choose the second option, just be careful do exactly the same as in the video...

Comment: Thank you so much for the info